# open/close instance of preview.app

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I have seen this question asked a number of times but I haven't been able to develop a working solution as yet.

I want to open an image ('preview' will do) display it for some seconds, and then either close that image to open a new one, or use the same instance to display a new image, rather than create a new instance.

I am using osx 10.12.6 and am just starting out with python3.

My aim is to create a "slideshow" that will display some 15,000 images as a background photoframe on a dedicated spare mac. There are too many images for slideshows in iPhoto, Preview etc. so I planned to write a simple one.... Ha! talk about draining the swamp!
thanks (in advance)

**sample code (so far)**

```
import PIL as Pillow    
from PIL import Image    
import os    
import re    
import string

os.listdir('/Slideshow')    
results = []    
for f in os.listdir('Slideshow'):
    print (f)
    if (f.startswith('.')):
       print('not showing this one')
    else:
       os.system("open 'Slideshow/'+ f")
       viewer = subprocess.Popen(["open", 'Slideshow/'+ f]) ##Opens the image to view 
       time.sleep(15)
       viewer.kill()
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: code added: each image opens in a new preview window, without any of them closing.

Comment: Consider having a look at using `feh` it is very fast and powerful. If your imagelist is too long, you can use its `-f ` option to specify a file containing a list of image names. Install using **homebrew**, with `brew install feh`. You need XQuartz with it but that is free and easy too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a few experiments on macOS Sierra by creating 10,000 different JPEG files with **ImageMagick** and **GNU Parallel** as follows:

```
parallel convert -size 800x600 xc:gray +noise random -quality 75 a-{}.jpg ::: {1..10000}
```

---

I created a list of 10,000 files and started **feh** without problem:

```
ls > filelist.txt
feh -f filelist.txt
```

---

I found you can pass a directory name (folder) to **Preview** app to get around the `Argument list too long` error. To do that, you have to press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd> and drag and drop the folder onto the **Preview** icon in your Dock.

I found that is able to load 8,862 images before crashing. I tried reducing the lengths of the filenames (from `longfilename-1.jpg` to `1-jpg`) to see if the lengths of the names were making a difference, but that did not help. I also tried reducing the quality of the JPEGs to reduce the memory demand, but that did not help either.

Not wishing to be outdone, I created 15 multi-page TIFF files each one containing 1,000 images. **Preview** managed to open all 15 documents, but got to 13,002 pages and crashed.

I am liking **feh** more and more...

Comment: Thank you Mark for investing so much time and posting the results. I am just using the basic Python stuff that is on Sierra and have avoided the HomeBrew or MacPorts installations so far. May have to go down this path it would seem.

Comment: I resisted installing software at first too, but have now used `homebrew` continuously for around 4 years and love it. I have never had a single problem with it - and I often install/uninstall several packages each day (in order to to configure my Mac to match people's environments and then answer StackOverflow questions). YMMV of course.